# Android: How to parse nested json array with different data type objects using retrofit - moshi?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

I want to parse nested json using retrofit moshi. The json data i'm having is an array, inside array first element is string & second is again an array.

I don't want to parse first element in the array (`"list"`), just want to parse second element from the array (i.e. Inner array).
But i'm facing challenges exactly here with the data object to be use.

Obviously we can use `Any` type in kotlin with list, but again will loose type of the object inside the list.

Json Format:

```
{
  "results": [
    "list",
    [
      {
        //jsonobj
      },
      {
        //jsonobj
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I want to parse json with this Data class that i have created without parsing first element & parse directly second element.

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    data class ResponseModel(
        @Json(name = "results")
        val results: List<Results?>?,
    ) {
        @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
        data class Results(
            @Json(name = "reference")
            val reference: String?,
            @Json(name = "enabled")
            val enabled: Boolean,
        )
    }
```

fromJson overridden function

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): C {
        val result = newCollection()
        reader.beginArray()
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            result?.add(elementAdapter.fromJson(reader)!!)
        }
        reader.endArray()
        return result
    }
```

This is throwing an exception saying `EXPECTED_OBJECT but it was STRING` when trying to parse first element (`"list"`).
i'm stuck here & not able to proceed further.

So can somebody plz help me to get out from here? any help will be appreciated.